# smtp connect() failed using PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I want to send a mail using `SMTP` and `PHP` and for that I am using `PHPMailer`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require 'class.phpmailer.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$body = 'Test Mail';
echo $body + '\r\n';
$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
//$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)

$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                 // sets the prefix to the server
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = 'mail@gmail.com';  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = '<password>';            // GMAIL password
$mail->SetFrom('mail@gmail.com', '<Name>');
$mail->AddReplyTo("replytomail@mail.com","<Name>");
$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "mailto@mail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "<Name>");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}
?>
```

The error is :

```
2016-01-28 04:37:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 11sm12390018pfq.87 - gsmtp
2016-01-28 04:37:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO ebusinessservices.in
2016-01-28 04:37:27 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [118.67.244.60] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
2016-01-28 04:37:27 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2016-01-28 04:37:28 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
2016-01-28 04:37:56 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2016-01-28 04:37:56 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2016-01-28 04:37:56 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

I tried to apply the answers from StackOverflow, checked credentials, tried using SSL with port 465 but getting same error.

In my gmail account, `Less Secure Apps` are allowed and 2-step verification is disabled. I tried to apply all the settings google provided for this to work but still getting same error.

Even according to some answers, I removed special characters from my password just to make sure that should not work as escape character but still its not working.

Please let me know the suggestions over this.

> I am trying to run the script from Server i.e. File is uploaded to web server.

**Update 1 : This is a error log after trying PHPMailer inbuilt script using my google credentials.**

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP b28sm13608414pfd.24 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO <name>
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [118.67.244.60]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
SMTP connect() failed.     https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: Check php openssl is enable or not, if not then enable it from your php.ini file, search ;extension=php_openssl.dll and remove the semi colon before it.

Comment: I know someone will tell this, that's why I added last line. The file is on web server, not local. So I can't edit php.ini

Thanks for the suggestion btw

Comment: This is most likely an SSL problem since it fails as soon as you try to use it. If you can't edit your php.ini, you need to find a proper hosting service. You've based your code on an obsolete example and are probably using an old version of PHPMailer, so get [the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). This is the *first thing* the guide says to check.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro, but the PHPMailer version is latest and SSL service is enabled by Hosting provider. I have already checked that.

Comment: So why did you base your code an an old example instead of the code that's supplied with PHPMailer? Did you see anything useful with `SMTPDebug=4`? Did you try disabling TLS verification? These are all covered in the guide.

Comment: I tried to use latest file but I am getting Server Error 500

Comment: So check your server logs to see where your PHP error is.